# Entity Relationship to retrieve data

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is the rate table. According to zone and cart weight, I want to give consumers an option to choose different available tier rates and the tier rates will be managed by the admin.
With Laravel, I am trying to structure this in RDBMS and I am stuck in managing the relationship of entities.
[image: rates]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provide, what makes more sense to me is just creating tables for the `zones` and `tier` entities. You would then need an additional table to keep the relation between those entities and the weight. Simple example:

```
// Zones
- id
- name
```

```
// Tiers
- id
- name
```

```
// Prices
- id
- zone_id
- tier_id
- weight
- price
```

Once you know the user zone and tier, you can just search on the price table filtering by weight.

Comment: thank you, price filtering by weight is solved, also Admin needs to update the price. With this relationship how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can simply run a query like this: 
`Price::where('zone_id', $zone_id)->where('tier_id', $tier_id)->update(['price' => $price]);`